# SIGABRT When using Parse PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I am trying to pull data from my Parse class called `Announce` but I am getting an error in the **main.m**. I've tried many things including resetting the simulator.

```
#import "AnnouncementTable.h"
#import "ParseUI/PFQueryTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface AnnouncementTable : PFQueryTableViewController
@end
@implementation AnnouncementTable : PFQueryTableViewController
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // This table displays items in the Todo class
        self.parseClassName = @"Announce";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache
    // first to fill the table and then subsequently do a query
    // against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HawkCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Header"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body: %@",
                                 [object objectForKey:@"Body"]];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

I'm fairly new to XCode but I'll try my best to answer any questions that you may have.

Many Thanks

Matt

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some more of your code? I don't see anything blatantly wrong but I would make sure that the spelling for all of your identifiers and Parse class names is correct. Also,

```
if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}
```

Make sure you don't have your local datastore enabled or this will cause an error, possibly a SIGABRT. Also,

```
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    self.objectsPerPage = 25;
```

I'm curious as to why you are disabling pagination but specifying the number of objects per page. This would have no effect. Also pagination is one of the best things about PFQueryTableViewController, if you don't need it you may be better off using a regular UITableViewController. Also,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Header"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body: %@",
                             [object objectForKey:@"Body"]];
```

Make sure that all of your calls to objectForKey are returning strings and not nil or something else.